# Pumping lemma: if you pump to $uv^0wx^0y$, wouldn't $|vx| \ngeq 1$?

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-grammar, pumping-lemma

For pumping lemma for CFLs, for strings $s$ in $L$, they follow the form $s = uvwxy$ and $|vwx| \leq n$, $|vx| \geq 1$, and $uv^iwx^iy \in L$ for $i \geq 0$.

If I want to prove a language is not CFL, could I not just pump to $uv^0wx^0p$ which would imply $|vx| \ngeq 1$, breaking a rule of PL?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio right. If for all $i \geq 0$, $uv^iwx^iy \in L$, then $uv^0wx^0y$ suggests $|vw| \ngeq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The pumping lemma for CFLs says, very roughly, that all sufficiently long strings in a context-free language can be pumped, and when pumped, the resulting strings will *always* belong to that language.
- In symbols, for every long string in a CFL, there's a way to decompose it into the form $\mathsf{uvwxy}$ with certain constraints on what $\mathsf{u,v,w,x,y}$ are, such that $\mathsf{uv}^k\mathsf{wx}^k\mathsf{y}$ is **always** part of the language for any $k\geq 0$.
- To prove that a language is not CFL, you generally argue "Suppose this language is context-free such that strings longer than $N$ are sufficiently long. Here I've made a carefully-constructed string longer than $N$. This means it can be decomposed into the appropriate form, obeying all the constraints. But look—no matter how it is decomposed, I can pump it to produce **a string not in the language**. This is a contradiction, so the language is not actually context-free."
- Your argument says, roughly "What if I decompose the string into the required form $\mathsf{uvwxy}$ then pump it down so that the resulting string **doesn't have that pumpable form** (because it's become too short)?" But that's not actually a problem—sometimes if you pump down a sufficiently long string, you'll get a string that is too short to be pumpable.

  The argument should be "What if I decompose the string into the required form $\mathsf{uvwxy}$ then pump it down so that it *isn't in the language anymore*?"   To use the pumping lemma, the evidence you're looking for is whether your starting string (in the correct form) can be pumped to produce strings that aren't in the language.

---

Consider the language $\{\mathtt{a}\mathtt{b}^n\mathtt{c}^n\mathtt{a} : n \geq 0\}$. It's context-free.  Still, you can take a string like $\mathtt{a}\mathtt{b}^N\mathtt{c}^N\mathtt{a}$ (which is pumpable) and pump it down to make a string like $\mathtt{a}\mathtt{a}$ which isn't pumpable—you can't find a pumpable decomposition where $|\mathsf{vx}|\geq 1$.  Still, the language is context-free—turning a pumpable string into a string that is too short to pump doesn't prove anything about being context-free.